# Copy Multiple Directories into One Directory Keeping the root folder using Robocopy

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batch script to copy multiple directories in different locations into one single directory in another location. The problem is that robocopy is copying the internal contents of the root directory and not the root directory itself

So If I have 3 directories in location a being :
**C:\dir1** , **C:\dir2** , **C:\dir3**

and I want to copy them to one single folder onto another location ex:
**D:\dirBackups**

so that the outcome would be **D:\dirBackups\dir1** , **D:\dirBackups\dir2**, **D:\dirBackups/dir3**

Currently robocopy is copying the stuff inside **dir1** , **dir2** and **dir3** so I am ending up with the contents of the three directories all into **D:\dirBackups**

I am using the following code

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%pathsFile%) do (
   robocopy %%A D:\dirBackups /E /COPYALL /XF /SEC /SECFIX /TIMFIX /W:0 /R:1 /REG /XJ /Z /FFT
)
```

***%pathsFile%*** is a text file which contains the directories to be backed up into **D:\dirBackups**, so I am looping through the file and for each line I am triggering the same robocopy Command.

The files are getting copied well but the root directory is never included so it's working like it's expanding all the folders and only copying the inner content of each folder into one location.

Thanks

Comment: It should be a back slash `D:\dirBackups` not a forward slash `D:/dirBackups`. Also you don't need to use `/SEC`, _which is equivalent to `/COPY:DATS`_, as you have already used `/COPYALL`, _which is equivalent to `/COPY:DATSOU`_. In addition your `/XF` option does not name any files to exclude, enter `ROBOCOPY /?` into a Command prompt window for more information on the command.

Comment: My Paths are infact using \ not / I did a mistake when typing this in... and thanks for  the information, but any clue how I can copy multiple folders from the root into one folder on another end ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this work for you?

```bat
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "USEBACKQ DELIMS=" %%A IN ("%pathsFile%") DO (
    ROBOCOPY "%%~A" "D:\dirBackups\%%~nxA" /E /Z /COPYALL /SECFIX /TIMFIX /XJ /FFT /R:1 /W:0 /REG
)
```

Comment: You're a life saver @Compo... Worked like a charm...If you can please explain the important parts of the code which made it happen I would really appreciate :) Thanks again ;)